# Used type 'UITextField' where arithmetic or pointer type is required?

Tags: objective-c

This is where I call my method (send message):

```
   [db saveSiteData:(UITextField) txtSiteID with:(UITextField) txtSTA and:(UITextField) txtSiteDesc and: (UITextField) txtElev ]
```

This is the declaration of the method:

```
- (void) saveSiteData:(UITextField*) txtSiteID STA:(UITextField*) txtSTA desc:(UITextField*) txtSiteDesc elev:(UITextField*) txtElev {
```

This is the error message I'm getting on the message call:

> Used type 'UITextField' where arithmetic or pointer type is required

How do I fix this?  (I'm a newbie, learning as fast as I can..) :D

Comment: The Subject/Title of your question refers to an error message that you don't actually mention in the body of your question. Can you edit the Title to reflect the actual error you received? Otherwise people searching for help with the "...where arithmetic or pointer type is required" error will land here but get no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
[db saveSiteData:(UITextField *) txtSiteID STA:(UITextField *) txtSTA desc:(UITextField *) txtSiteDesc elev: (UITextField *) txtElev ]
```

Comment: I did that and now I'm getting this error:

No visible @interface for 'slSQLite' declares the selector 'saveSiteData:with:and:and:'

I'm really confused by "with" and "and"... it must have something to do with the declaration, but I don't know what.. (got them out of the book in an example)

Comment: txtSideID and all the others are UITextFields that you want to send to the method?

Comment: yes... as I just indicated, I think my declaration is messed up... what is "with" and "and" with relation to declaring a method?

Comment: You are not calling the same method, as you said you are messing up with the parts of it

Comment: @spokane-dude: In Objective-C, arguments to method invocations are named, and the signature of a method incorporates those names, delineated with colons. It's not called a 'signature' though, it's called a 'selector'. So the `saveSiteData:with:and:and:` string is a selector, and the error you mention above is telling you that your method is not declared publicly in any @interface that the compiler can find. A deep dive into The Objective-C Programming Guide will do you well.

Comment: Oh my gawd!  It's working!  Thanks to all three of you... I really, really appreciate your time and patience.  I will read the Guide, but it's not the clearest thing written!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `UITextField` objects as parameters:

```
[db saveSiteData:txtSiteID STA:txtSTA desc:txtSiteDesc elev:txtElev];
```

And read at least this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

PS. This will be more useful - [The Objective-C Programming - Object Messaging](http://Languagehttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW5)